# Vector of class pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I know that there are several similar questions previously asked. But none of them are answered with wide recognition and the vector of pointers are still very confusing to me.

Here is the code:
Imagine we have a:

```
vector<member*> vector_member;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
    member* mem = new member(i); //constructor
    mem->init(); //This function use a random number generator to give the member some randomness
   vector_member.push_back(mem);
}
```

After executing this code, I find that the all the random number for vector_member[i] are the same!

Any experts have any idea about this?

Comment: Any chance you could show us the member class, or the init function?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong here (although juggling raw pointers is asking for trouble). What does `init` do? We can't guess why the numbers might be the same without seeing how they're generated.

Comment: There's so much here that we can't see, including the actual creation of the numbers you're complaining about, that this question is unanswerable. Post your [testcase](http://sscce.org) when you write a debugging question. Thanks.

Comment: never do this. use a vector of smart pointers. But its not why you have issue. HOw do you know they are all the same?

Comment: If `init` isn't working, do you suppose it would help if we could see its source code? As far as the code goes in general: vectors of pointers are rarely useful, and you show nothing to justify them here. Having an `init` member function pretty much stinks of 2-phase initialization, which you *really* want to avoid.

Comment: I bet that `init` re-seeds the random number generator with a constant.

Comment: @RobH: Or even `time(0)^getpid()` will do since this is likely to happen over a sub-second period of time.

Comment: Why do you think that *vector* and *pointer* are factors affecting the random number generation? Do you get the expected result if you don't use vectors and pointers, but only create a series of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to see your `init` method, but my guess would be that your random function is using a seed value like the current time (eg in milliseconds since the epoch) to initialize itself, and your code is executing so quickly that the time hasn't changed between calls, so it returns the same random number.

Comment: You forgot to actually provide a solution. Anyway, we shouldn't do that until the OP has learnt to present his testcase.

Comment: All right, thank you for your answer and you are right. The question is in random seed. Now the question becomes: how to generate N random number or N random seed at the same time?

Comment: @LAWRENCE: Only seed the generator once.